# Google Cloud Storage - Public object with cache-control "no-store" still stored

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a file that change every few seconds on google bucket. File is public readable, so if I not pass a cache-control value, file is automagically cached.

I'm pushing file on storage with gsutil from inside a bash script, like this:

```
gsutil cp filename.ext gs://bucket/directory/filename.ext && gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://bucket/directory/filename.ext
```

Then update cache-control with this code:

```
 gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:no-store" \
         h "Content-Disposition" gs://bucket/directory/filename.ext
```

My file is not cached first times i call it, after few calls file being cached.

On google cloud, file actually has no-store parameter
[image]

I can't use inside URL that calls the file parameter to prevent cache (parameter like noCache=1 -> don't remember the exactly parameter, but in this case can't use it)

Comment: Are you sure the object is being cached on Cloud Storage side? Do you have a request example in which the object was cached? This would be helpful to understand the behaviour that you are seeing as based on your description, it shouldn't be cached anywhere.

Comment: Actually I've found the problem. By making the upload and the cache-control settings consecutively, if browser got the file just one moment before correct cache-control is setted, my browser just got always the cached version. 
Solved by adding cache-control directly while cp the file on bucket.